# How get names of lxc containers from host?

Tags: dnsmasq, lxd

The `lxd` by default creates the bridged network in the `managed`  dns.mode. One of the features of this mode is that all containers see each other by their name (not only by the ip address). E.g. from container "`c1`" I can query the default name server for IP address of another container c2 with `nslookup c2`.

That's cool.

But it doesn't work on the host. I know I can query the `lxc list`  for the ip addresses of the containers, but it is a pain to do if I only want a simple `ssh root@c1`.

I came up to the point when I realized that the solution would require customizing the `dnsmasq` settings that serves names for the bridges. I gave up when I discovered that the best candidate setting is `--auth-server`. The man says

> Configuring  dnsmasq  to  act as an authoritative DNS server is complicated by the fact  that  it  involves  configuration  of  external  DNS servers  to provide delegation.

I don't want to register my home dynamic ip network on outside (dyn)dns service. I just want the container names be visible in the host (and even better on my whole lan)

Comment: It might be a lot easier if you choose custom columns: `lxc list "my-container" -c 4`

Comment: To expand, if all you want is to use `ssh`, try `ssh root@$(lxc list "my-container" -c 4 | awk '!/IPV4/{ if ( $2 != "" ) print $2}')`. The command substitution alone works in any other scenario *from the host*. Admittedly, that won't get the name visible from anywhere else on LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
server=/lxd/10.150.161.1
```

to your /etc/dnsmasq.conf and restart the dnsmasq service.  After that

```
nslookup ‹containter_name›.lxd
```

should work.

This assumes you use the currently default setup of running a dnsmasq daemon as a local DNS server (check whether your /etc/resolv.conf lists 127.0.0.x as the nameserver).  The quoted config line instructs this nameserver to query 10.150.161.1 for addresses in the .lxd domain.  A secondary dnsmasq runs there, which was set up by LXD installation — this is what your containers listen to.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to reach your containers by their hostname from your host, you need to run the following commands:

```
resolvectl dns lxdbr0 [lxdbr0 IP]
resolvectl domain lxdbr0 lxd
```

It should work fine after executing the above two commands.